# Error while setting path variable using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am getting the below Error while setting path variable using Batch file:

ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
Press any key to continue . . .

```
@echo off


  SETX PATH "%PATH%";"C:\Users\Work\0505" /M

 pause
```

Comment: `SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\Work\0505" /M` ?

Comment: The issue is that a semicolon is a separator in batch, so `"%PATH%";"C:\Users\Work\0505"` is seen as two separate strings - as if the `;` was a space.